# django-nonrel backends with deferred not working

Tags: google-app-engine, background, backend, deferred, django-nonrel

I have a problem with the app engine backends instance, I am using 
django-nonrel and I tried the deferred.defer both in 
development and in production and here is the result:
On Development (testing in my computer) the 
deferred.defer with _target:backend_name, worked and I could see that used 
the backend instance.
On Production, deferred.defer didn't work, the backend instance is not starting, the 
_ah/start is giving the 500 error, with all the backend instance 
configuration that I tried (resident, dynamic, public, B1, B2, B4, etc)
So I have no more ideas and I couldn't find anyone in the same situation as 
me, if anyone could help I appreciate.
Please let me know if needed more information.

Regards

Fabio

Comment: Can you direct me to a documentation to follow to implement deferred.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I solved the problem already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,

App engine was not finding the 404 page, once I solved this the backend worked.